# Ubuntu installation will not boot, throws error missing file: /dev/sdc1

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04, dev

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 and received the continuous message loop:

```
udev[number]: timeout: killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sdc' [number]
```

I suspect this error happens due to a missing `/dev/sdc` file. It would be great if I could have some insight resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdc` is a device link to the third mass storage device (hard drive, external drive or USB stick) in the network.

Looking at your question's edit history, I came across this *(Using Win7 OS)* notice. Be careful, to install Ubuntu, you will need to boot from the CD/DVD disc or the USB drive itself, you can't do that inside Ubuntu.

The error sounds like you are trying to use an invalid drive or partition to install the system. Or, that you are using the installer from an USB stick. Sometimes the USB install can crap up and turn out to be a disrespectful child (this is more common with the Server installer) and deny to install itself. You should try to either burn a CD/DVD disk and boot from there or to create your bootable USB stick with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Always choose to format the whole USB stick when you create the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to understand what this error is telling you. From what I could determine, you are trying to run the `blkid` program. Here's a [short definition](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/blkid.8.html) of what `blkid` is:

> The `blkid` program is the command-line interface to working with `libblkid(3)` library. It can determine the type of content (e.g. filesystem, swap) a block device holds, and also attributes (tokens, NAME=value pairs) from the content metadata (e.g. LABEL or UUID fields).

Now that we know that `blkid` is a program that tries to deal with drives, we might assume it can't find the "sdc" drive (which "looks" like a file since everything in Linux looks like a file). Then again, it might be having trouble writing the file "udev" to the sdc drive (or directory).

But since I see no error about file permissions I might assume it's just a matter of a missing hard drive. (FYI: sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, etc. are usually names for for hard drives that don't necessarily have to be exclusively connected to a SATA/PATA/SCSI controller either). So that's my best guess – it's a missing drive, partition, or sub-directory that's causing the error.

Just why you're getting this error is something else. You didn't really give us any info on what you did or observed that might have caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this strange issue too, when installing dual-boot MacOs and Ubuntu **on an iMac 2012**. Sometimes it occurs, sometimes not.

Try to stop you machine, keep it stopped for 30 seconds, put the USB drive in **another** USB slot and start again. That seems to help.

Success!